# Can't change ubuntu linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

In server default kernel is 2.6.32-042stab141.3 I want to upgrade to 3 or higher I tried these steps

wget [http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.11.2/linux-headers-4.11.2-041102_4.11.2-041102.201705201036_all.deb](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v4.11.2/linux-headers-4.11.2-041102_4.11.2-041102.201705201036_all.deb)
wget [http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.11.2/linux-headers-4.11.2-041102-generic_4.11.2-041102.201705201036_amd64.deb](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v4.11.2/linux-headers-4.11.2-041102-generic_4.11.2-041102.201705201036_amd64.deb)
wget [http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.11.2/linux-image-4.11.2-041102-generic_4.11.2-041102.201705201036_amd64.deb](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v4.11.2/linux-image-4.11.2-041102-generic_4.11.2-041102.201705201036_amd64.deb)

dpkg -i *.deb

sudo update-grub

reboot

uname -a output: Linux trenim 2.6.32-042stab141.3

after these steps, the Linux kernel has not changed.

Comment: You're stuck in an openvz container. Your kernel is handled by your host provider, not by you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, you're right my kernel was handled by the hosting provider